# Как исправить ошибку MaxPoolSize (NpgSql) asp.net core?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, dapper

Буквально два дня назад стала появляться ошибка, то ли после обновления (добавления дополнительных модулей) то ли из за наплыва пользователей

> NpgsqlException: The connection pool has been exhausted, either raise MaxPoolSize (currently 100) or Timeout (currently 15 seconds)

Приложение на Asp.net core + postgres + npgsql + dapper
Linux + kestrel + Nginx

В репозиториях, везде после запроса закрываю соединение

```
dbConnection.Close();
```

Ошибка появляется тогда когда active connection (nginx) 1900-2200

1. В чем может быть причина?
2. нигде не нашел информацию сколько максимум можно указать MaxPoolSize (ngpsql)?
   Могу ли указать 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваше приложение неправильно построено. При каждом запросе к БД у вас создаётся новое соединение с БД. Так делать не нужно. Это сильно увеличивает нагрузку на БД и время выполнения. `postgresql` борется с этим и ограничивает количество подключений (до 1000), что вы его не положили. Вы должны использовать одно соединение для работы с БД. Его нет смысла закрывать и открывать новое.

Если у вас нет сейчас возможности изменить логику работы сервера, то используйте [bgbouncer](https://www.pgbouncer.org/). Это прослойка между вашим приложением и БД. Он берёт все ваши подключения и соединяет их в 1, чтобы не нагружать БД. Но это в каком-то роде костыль.

**Важно:** Ни в коем случае не увеличивайте количество возможных подключений! Это не решение проблемы, ваша БД и скорость работы сервера будут страдать, пока БД не откажет в обслуживании и не прекратит работать

Comment: В репозиториях я обращаюсь к БД так: using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection){ dbConnection.Open(); await dbConnection.ExecuteAsync(“INSERT INTO....”); dbConnection.Close();} потом обращаюсь к нему через сервисы.  то есть так не правильно? Можно пример?;) я могу изменить логику

Comment: @Pupkin я не знаю C# и ASP.NET, поэтому не могу подсказать как вам это сделать. предполагаю, что `dbConnection.Open()` открывает соединение с БД. Вы должны делать это 1 раз при запуске сервера (ну либо более 1 раза, если соединение по непонятным причинам закрылось). Используйте это соединение во всех запросах и не закрывайте его. Если `ASP.NET` не даёт реализовать такое (не самый вариант для веб-разработки, от него можно ожидать всё :D ), то используйте pgbouncer.